# Full validation in change sets still needed in unlocked package installation?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, unlocked-package, cicd

My team would like to gradually replace change set deployment model with unlocked packages. I did some experiments and found out that installing package in an org is somehow like running partial deployment using change sets.

As far as I know, some errors can only be found out with full validation. (Don't know if it is called integration test).

Do people still run full validation in Production before installing a new version of package into Production?

Comment: By validation do you mean running apex test classes ?

Comment: Yes. Like this "sfdx force:apex:test:run"

Answer (score 3):

So far tests are not required for Unlocked Packages, however starting Winter '21, they will be required and run when you create a package version as explained [here](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004qE3RF).

You can currently validate the tests of your package using the `--codecoverage` flag during the package version creation (`sfdx force:package:version:create`).

However, these tests are run during creation, not installation. As you said, you'll have to run `sfdx force:apex:test:run` manually to be sure that all tests are valid.

Comment: The one of Winter '21 new policy is 75% coverage of the unlocked package itself instead of the whole org I guess. My real concern is that some test classes outside of the package may not pass after a new package creation. And this will not be detected if one does not specify "sfdx force:apex:test:run" before the creation.

Comment: Got it, but running sfdx force:apex:test:run manually is the only option you have so far.

Comment: You can still reply on the Chatter feed I posted and ask for this feature though.